# Using :after CSS selector to fill a space?

Tags: css, css-selectors

On [this page](http://carolineelisa.com/indigo/2012) I wish to have the entire space to the right of the navigation filled in white.

So, I achieved 5px wide white block using the :after CSS selector, and am hoping there is a way to make it fit the available width, although I am open to other suggestions!:

```
#menu-main-menu:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background:#fff;
    width:5px;
    height:30px;
    float:right;
    }
```

Here is the simplified HTML:

```
<div class="menu"><ul id="menu-main-menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Courses &#038; prices</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Activities in Rio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Accommodation</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And all the relevant CSS:

```
#primary-menu ul {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#primary-menu li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
#primary-menu a {
    color:#333;
    background: #fff;
    display:block;
}
#primary-menu .current-menu-item a, #primary-menu .current-page-parent a {
    color:#fff;
    background:none;
}
#menu-main-menu:before {
content:"";
display:block;
background:#fff;
width:20px;
height:30px;
float:left;
} 
#menu-main-menu:after {
content:"";
display:block;
background:#fff;
width:5px;
height:30px;
float:right;
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to check out my question!

Caroline

Comment: Should the width of the `:before` and the width of the `:after` be equal? As it is, if I make the `:after` be the correct width, your menu isn't centered. Is it supposed to be centered?

Comment: Only just saw your comment now sorry thirtydot. No, the menu is not supposed to be centered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the `::after` pseudo selector to the `li.current-menu-item` instead of `#menu-main-menu` and add white background from that element onwards.

```
.current-menu-item:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    content: "";
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -1000px;   /* these numbers are the same */
    top: 0;
    width: 1000px;    /* and need to be at least the width of the menu */
}

#primary-menu li {
    position: relative;  /* position the ::after element relative to the li */
}

#primary-menu ul {
    ....
    overflow: hidden;  /* you already have this to clear your floats */
    ....               /* but I thought I should emphasise that you need it */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Afraid I can't get it to work though. Do I need to remove any other CSS, other than #menu-main-menu:after?

Comment: @CarolineElisa You haven't added `position: relative` to `#primary-menu li`

Comment: Oops, I think I was looking before your edit and then after and messed them up! Thank you!!!

Comment: No problem, it was an interesting problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The example below works by adding an extra `li` to fill, but since the font will render dirrentely among browsers you cannot predict the width.  The workaround in this example  creates a container (`#cen`) for centering the content and setting the width, also the `overflow` property is set to hidden.   Doing this you are able to add a significantly bigger `div` wrapping the `ul` and the filler `li` with a lot more width than required.  Which causes no problem since the parent.parent is hidding overflows.

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/3YpDh/1/

```
<div id="cen">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Courses &#038; prices</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Activities in Rio</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Accommodation</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       <li class="filler">&nbsp;</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</div>


#cen {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu {
    width: 1200px;
    float:left;
 }

li {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    float:left;
    background: white;
}

.filler {
    width: 200px;       
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, but the white filler cannot be a fixed width as the menu needs to be flexible...

Comment: @CarolineElisa To get around that the solution uses large widths for `#menu` and `.filler`.  You can bump it to `3000px` or more if you want

Comment: Thanks again Eric. I tried to do that in the fiddle, but it bumped the filler to the next line.

Comment: you need to bump both `.menu` and `.filler`

Comment: P.s. I have accepted the other answer, as it only involves editing CSS not HTML. But I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of `float` on `li` allows you to simply define **`display: block;`** `background: white` on their **`ul`** parent without any need for `:before` and `:after` pseudos to fill a space. This `ul` will already be 100% width because of `display: block`.

To do this, you can display each item as **`inline-block`** (`display: inline` and `zoom: 1` for IE6/7) and stick closing and opening `</li><li>` tags to avoid whitespace between them.

**[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u9dA/)**

Bonus in the fiddle: in a second example, items occupy all available width (not necessarily pretty, depends of your design and menu) by using **`table-cell`** (the CSS value, not the unsemantic `table>tr>td` HTML code, of course). For IE6/7, same fallback as above (and same rendering).

Comment: Thanks Felipe, but I specifically don't want to add `background:#fff` to the `ul` because I want the selected `li` to be transparent and show the page beneath.